# How to self-define a Python function with optional parameters?

Tags: python

There are a bunch of discussions on this kind of issue here, but I did not see anything about how to implement such a function.

Say I have a class `Foo()` that has a function `bar()` inside.

The function `bar()` takes in **either no or only one argument**. When it takes in nothing, the attribute is set to 2. Else, it is set to whatever the input is. i.e.

```
In [32]: foo = Foo()
In [33]: foo.bar()
In [34]: foo.a
Out [34]: 2
```

and

```
In [32]: foo = Foo()
In [33]: foo.bar(5)
In [34]: foo.a
Out [34]: 5
```

How do I do this?

Comment: **To Downvoters**: Give your reason, please.

Comment: duplicate of many-many questions, perhaps?

Comment: This is a rather basic question; a quick google for 'python optional arguments' provides a rich and varied response to your question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm pretty sure, it's because you haven't typed your question in Google

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a [keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

```
def bar(self, value=2):
    self.a = value
```

Here `value` defaults to `2` if not explicitly given:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar()
>>> foo.a
2
>>> foo.bar(5)
>>> foo.a
5
```

Note that the function signature is created *once*; defaults are stored on the function object. A common mistake is to assume that defaults are evaluated each time you call a function, and that can lead to some surprises:

```
import datetime

def ham(now=datetime.datetime.now()):
    print now
```

Here `now` will be fixed to the moment `bar` was imported and Python created the function object:

```
>>> ham()
2013-10-24 10:20:26.024775
>>> # wait some time
...
>>> ham()
2013-10-24 10:20:26.024775
```

It gets more surprising still when the default value is mutable:

```
def eggs(param, value=[]):
    value.append(param)
    print value
```

Repeatedly calling `eggs(2)` will result in the `value` list growing, adding a new value `2` to the list each time you call it:

```
>>> eggs(2)
[2]
>>> eggs(2)
[2, 2]
>>> eggs(2)
[2, 2, 2]
```

See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for a longer discussion about this.

Comment: And it might be great to mention an [infamous caveat with lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)

Comment: Thanks! I have read that post before. Now finally I can link it with my question!

Answer (score 0):

You *can* give parameters a default value. Just define it as a keyword argument:

```
def bar(self, param=2):
    self.a = param
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea sorry. Updated it.

Comment: Now fixed. Kind of sleepy.